# Download a excel file through Zend

Tags: http-headers, zend-framework2

I need to give download excel files stored on server. But I am unable to find an example for download in ZF2. I am trying for the following code

```
$response = new Response();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="forecast_template.xlsx"',
    'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0',
));
$response->setContent(file_get_contents($xlsx_file_name));
```

But it did not work. I tried setRawBody but that gave error for undefined method. Also I tried "echo $response", But that just dump string output for headers + binary data.

Comment: Yes, I am using ZF2 MVC. This is code is part of my controller action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using MVC, you can start a file download by `short-circuiting` the `MvcEvent` (to do this, just return the `Response` instance instead of a `ViewModel`).

The following example snippet works for me:

```
use Zend\Http\Headers;

(...)

$response = $this->getEvent()->getResponse();
$response->setHeaders(Headers::fromString("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Length: 9\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"blamoo.txt\""));

$response->setContent('blablabla');

return $response;
```